# Cron Job Ubuntu With Special Command

Tags: ubuntu, cron, python

I have this command `python myscript.py -rss` and it's working well in the terminal but not inside `crontab`.

I have this in my crontab´:

```
*/15 * * * * cd /var/www/html && /usr/bin/python /var/www/html/myscript.py -rss >> /var/www/html/myscript.log
```

and it's not working… there is nothing in the log.

Comment: `/var/www/html` sounds like a web site document root. You should definitely keep scripts and their log files out of there, or else they are susceptible to being accidentally published to the world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set the cron-job using  root? It could be some permission issue.